# What is the reason for $\frac{3}{4\sqrt{x}}$ to not be differentiable in $x_{0} = 0$?

Tags: calculus

What is the reason for $\frac{3}{4\sqrt{x}}$ to not be differentiable in $x_{0} = 0$? Can I say that it's because $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}$$ is undefined?

Comment: $f(0)$ not being defined is enough?

Comment: it's because 0 is not in the domain of the function

Answer (score 2):

$f(0)$ and hence, $f'(0)$ are not defined. Period.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is very simple and has been answered before, so I wanna give some points regarding differentiablity of functions in a point:

1. From the definition of a differentiable function it comes out that a differentiable function on a real variable is a function whose derivative exists at each point in its domain.
2. So the graph of a differentiable function must have exactly one (non-vertical) tangent line at each point in its domain. In other words it should has no cusps and bends and breaks.

In the case of your question to use the first property is enough. Which says that if the point is not in the domain of the function, and the function is undefined on it, then the function is not differentiable on that point.

And we are done, since your function is not defined at $x_0 = 0.$